# How to get UserName from java.sql.Connection?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, weblogic, jndi

I have a data source for SQLServer created in Weblogic with username 'sa'.

In code I am using following to get user name.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
Object obj = ctx.lookup("sqlserver1");
System.out.println("Data Source Found….");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) obj;
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData mtdt = conn.getMetaData();
// Get UserName
System.out.println("User name: " + mtdt.getUserName());
```

But above code always returns 'dbo' as the username. I expected the username to be 'sa'. If the DB is Oracle it works fine. Is there a generic way for me to get user name for all different types of database.

Answer (score 4):

The correct method should be `DatabaseMetaData.getUserName()`, but as you demonstrate not all databases implement that correctly. Another way would be to use the JDBC function escape `USER()` eg (eg `SELECT {fn USER()} FROM DUAL`), but not all drivers implement all JDBC escapes, and it could just be that this returns the same as the `DatabaseMetaData`. You could also try the SQL standard defined `CURRENT_USER` (or `USER`) in a query, but there you have two problems: 1) some databases require you to select from a table (eg `DUAL` in Oracle, some don't) and 2) not all databases implement all parts of the SQL standards, so the `CURRENT_USER` or `USER` context variable might be absent.

But as you have the DataSource object, you could try to get the `user` property from the datasource (it is defined in table 9.1 of the JDBC 4.1 specification, although the property names described there are not all required).

So for example:

```
Method getter = new PropertyDescriptor("user", ds.getClass()).getReadMethod();
String value = (String) getter.invoke(ds);
```

This assume that 1) the `DataSource ds` has a `getUser()` and 2) that it is actually set (for example with SQL Server integrated security the datasource doesn't need to know about a user).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Java 1.7 provides the [Connection.getSchema()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema%28%29) method.  I don't know how widely 1.7 has been adopted at this point however, so this might just be something to keep in mind for future reference.